# Get propery of other React component in a library

Tags: reactjs

I'm writing a library full of ReactJS components, so Flux should not be used, since it's a library.

I have a component, a `ThemeProvider`.

```
import React from 'react';

class OfficeUIThemeProvider extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return null;
    }
}

OfficeUIThemeProvider.propTypes = {
  theme: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['Office2016']).isRequired,
  color: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['Light-Blue', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Purple', 'Red']).isRequired
};

export default OfficeUIThemeProvider;
```

I return `null` in the `render()` method since this component should not render anything.

Then I do have a simple component, a button.

```
import React from 'react';

class OfficeUIButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return  <div className={"officeui-button"}>
                    <span className="{officeui-button-label}">{this.props.label}</span>
                </div>
    }
}

OfficeUIButton.propTypes = {
    label: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default OfficeUIButton;
```

Now, I want the button to have specific classes, based on the values provided in the `ThemeProvider`.

A simple solution would be to render the `OfficeUIButton` component directly in my `ThemeProvider` `render()` method but this is not a valid solution since I'm developing a library and don't want to couple things.

An application using this library should work as:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <OfficeUIThemeProvider theme='Office2016' color='Light-Blue'>
        <OfficeUIButton label="To..." />
    </OfficeUIThemeProvider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

But, this renders nothing since my `ThemeProvider` return `null○ in it's`render` method.

How can this be accomplished?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OfficeUIButton is child component of OfficeUIThemeProvider, so I suppose you should try:

```
class OfficeUIThemeProvider extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This renders `ERROR in ./source/core/components/officeui-theme-provider/officeui-theme-provider.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Dev/officeui-react/source/core/components/officeui-theme-provider/officeui-theme-provider.jsx: Unexpected token, expected , (47:20)` in Webpack.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited